# If $ ax^2 + 2bx + c = 0 $ and $ a_1x^2 + 2b_1x + c_1 = 0 $ have a common root , then prove the following.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

If $a/a_1 , b/b_1 , c/c_1 $ are in A.P.  then $ a_1 , b_1 , c_1 $ are in G.P.

I have no idea , how to approach this .

What I have thought :

For the AP series 
$ a/a_1 = k - d $

the rest be k & k + d respectively

The condition for common root here in this case is :

$$ (ca_1 - c_1a )^2 = ( ab_1 - a_1b ) ( bc_1 - b_1c ) $$

Replacing a , b , c with : $ ( k - d ) a_1 , k b_1 , ( k + d ) c_1 $ 
now thats too messy . Is there a better approach .

Comment: Can you explain please what is A.P. and G.P.?

Comment: This is not a homework site! Please show what you have tried or think! :)

Comment: @Stef Arithmetic Progression and Geometric Progression .

Comment: @H.R. Posting right away :/

Comment: @Ricky, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=a_1(k-d)$, $b=b_1k$ and $c=c_1(k+d)$ now $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ becomes

$$a_1(k-d)x^2+2b_1kx+c_1(k+d)=0$$ $\implies$

$$k(a_1x^2+2b_1x+c_1)-a_1dx^2+c_1d=0 \tag{1}$$ and

the other quadratic is $$a_1x^2+2b_1x+c_1=0 \tag{2}$$ If $(1)$ and $(2)$ have common root $\alpha$ we have

from $(1)$

$$k(0)-a_1d \alpha^2+c_1d=0$$ $\implies$

$$\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}$$ and substitute this in $(2)$ we get

$$a_1(\frac{c_1}{a_1})+2b_1\sqrt{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}+c_1=0$$ simplifying this we get $$b_1^2=a_1c_1$$

Answer (score 1):

I thought it will be messy , but apparently its not .

I will proceed from 
$a = ( k - d ) a_1 , b = kb_1 , c = ( k + d )c_1$

Now in this case , applying the condition for a single common root in two equations :

$$ ( ca_1 - c_1a )^2 = ( 2bc_1 - 2b_1c ) ( 2ab_1 - 2a_1b ) $$

Replacing $ a,b,c $ with  $ ( k - d ) a_1 , kb_1 , ( k + d )c_1 $

$$ \implies ( 2 c_1a_1d )^2 = ( -2a_1b_1d ) ( -2b_1c_1d ) $$ 
$$ \implies a_1c_1 = { b_1 }^2 $$